# PHP uploading an excel file

Tags: php, date, insert

In my code, I am trying to create a new table that will be called the current date of today. The problem is the date code is not being pushed through so no table is created at all. I've gotten it to create the table if I didn't name it by the variable but that is not the output I want. It should create a new table EACH AND EVERY TIME  the program is ran. Any help please??

```
if ($result) {

    echo ' Success ';
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $uploadDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $qry1 = "CREATE TABLE $uploadDate (fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,middleInitial VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,building VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,room VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,dept VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,phone INT(10) NOT NULL,position VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)";
    $qry2 = "INSERT into $uploadDate (fname,lname,middleInitial,building,room,dept,phone,position,email) VALUES('$filesop[0]','$filesop[1]','$filesop[2]','$filesop[3]','$filesop[4]','$filesop[5]','$filesop[6]','$filesop[7]','$filesop[8]')";
    $result1 = $uc->query($qry1);
    $result2 = $uc->query($qry2);

    // if(mysqli_query($uc, $qry1))
    if($result1){   
        if($result2)
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Retry Query!";
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what works and what doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
$uploadDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

Your table name is e.g 2016-01-01. It's not allowed to have - in table name (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>   ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>   Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF